# Can you override single submit forms?

Tags: forms

I have a form that generates some custom financial reports (can't use Views).  It has some typical form elements, a table of results, and three submit buttons: Submit, Reset, and Download.

Submit and Reset do what you think. Download triggers a submit handler that builds a CSV from the `$form['table']` in the handler (which is what the user has generated, and prevents another complicated database query + computations and another route to essentially do the same work), and then spits it out with a `$form_state->setResponse($response)`.  This works great.

I discovered an interesting edge case, though, during testing.

core/misc/form.es6.js has a section of code in it (lines 117-134 in Drupal 8.8.5):

```
Drupal.behaviors.formSingleSubmit = {
  attach() {
    function onFormSubmit(e) {
      const $form = $(e.currentTarget);
      const formValues = $form.serialize();
      const previousValues = $form.attr('data-drupal-form-submit-last');
      if (previousValues === formValues) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        $form.attr('data-drupal-form-submit-last', formValues);
      }
    }

    $('body')
      .once('form-single-submit')
      .on('submit.singleSubmit', 'form:not([method~="GET"])', onFormSubmit);
  },
};
```

This prevents a form from being submitted more than once if it hasn't changed.  However, since my Download button is a submit handler, the above code runs, which then prevents the Reset button from working unless another form element has been changed.

My current workaround is a bit of a sledgehammer:

```
Drupal.behaviors.sledgehammer = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('form.my-form', context).on('submit', function (e) {
      var $form = $(e.currentTarget);
      $form.removeAttr('data-drupal-form-submit-last');
    });
  }
};
```

As far as I can tell this works, but I have BigPipe turned on and am going to AJAX up the form a bit, so I am worried that this may be fragile.

Is there an JS API way to disable the single-submit behavior, or is a workaround the only solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already, try using [button](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Button.php/class/Button/8.6.x) rather than submit type.

```
'#type' => 'button',
```

> When the button is pressed, the form will be submitted to Drupal,
>   where it is validated and rebuilt. **The submit handler is not invoked**.

Perhaps this will prevent that `formSingleSubmit` behavior from running???

---

If the above doesn't work, since all the `formSingleSumit` behaviour does is prevent form from being submitted if it hasn't changed and nothing else. Therefore, you don't need this behaviour and since `Drupal` is global, you could just do in custom.js:

```
delete Drupal.behaviors.formSingleSubmit;
```

OR set it/override it to empty

```
Drupal.behaviors.formSingleSubmit = {};
```